# Ubuntu 15.04 PlayOnLinux Evernote can't edit notes

Tags: ubuntu, wine, playonlinux

Just installed Ubuntu 15.04 (yes, I know that I'm a slowpoke). On Ubuntu 14.10 I was using Evernote via POL and everything was OK.

Now I have a weird problem. Everything is synced. I can see a list of my notes but...

I can't edit any. I only see the title, text but I can't change it. In main list I only see content of the first note. When I select another note - nothing changes, I only see the first note.

I can Open note in new window - I see it correctly but I can't edit it.

What's it and how to fix it?

POL 4.2.5 wine 1.7.52

Comment: Which version of Evernote are you using?

Comment: Evernote version 5.9.1

Answer (score 2):

According to this [post](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/66262-running-evernote-using-wine-on-linux/?p=382156) , Evernote 5.9.x has problem with the editor. You can download 5.8.x [here](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/86114-new-evernote-for-windows-5813-ga-update/).

Comment: Installed 5.8. Had a problem with "Couldn't connect to server". Tried different versions of wine - 1.4 worked for me. So, for now - wine 1.4 + Evernote 5.8 works well.

Comment: By the way, you can take a look at [this](https://plus.google.com/+EinVerne/posts/faXLWtQGCZD).

Answer (score 0):

To use Evernote 5.9 and 6.x (tested with versions up to 6.4.2) with PlayOnLinux, create bottle based on the `1.8-steam_crossoverhack`. Additionally you could want to apply `FontsSmoothRGB` and `Microsoft Core Fonts` components to the created bottle.